# Нужно ли ставить запятую в конструкции "<глагол> и поэтому <глагол>"

Tags: пунктуация, однородные-члены

**Данная роль государства используется в основном при реализации инфраструктурных проектов(?) и поэтому не рассматривается в диссертационном исследовании.**

Нужна ли запятая на месте вопроса?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мне режет слух "*роль.. используется*". Я бы предложил употребить "*роль... важна*" или перестроить предложение:

**В данной роли государство выступает в основном при реализации инфраструктурных проектов, и поэтому она не рассматривается в диссертационном исследовании.**

Answer (score 1):

Данная роль государства **используется** в основном при реализации инфраструктурных проектов **и поэтому не рассматривается** в диссертационном исследовании.

В предложении данной структуры сказуемые считаются **однородными** (нет запятой перед одиночным союзом И), но отношения между ними не равноправные, а осложненные причинно-следственной связью (наречие ***поэтому***).

Сравнить: Этот маяк более высокий и поэтому более заметный.

Comment: Очень интересно с теоретический точки зрения (об однородности и причинно-следственной связи), поэтому я голосую за этот ответ. Но... Неужели Вы считаете, что слова "роль" и  "используется" сочетаются между собой?

Comment: Можно сказать: данная функция государства используется или задействована.... При правке важно внести минимальные изменения структуры предложения.

Answer (score 0):

Запятая не нужна. "**Используется**" и "**не рассматривается**" – однородные сказуемые при подлежащем "**роль государства**". Запятая не ставится, если два однородных члена предложения соединены союзом "**и**".